# delete map marker while dragged on an ImageView bounds

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I am using the google map api v2. I place markers on map long click, i would like to delete them when dragged over the android "ic_delete" drawable bounds i set at the left of the map (as it is done when we delete an app in the launcher). Help !

**HERE IS MY CODE:**

```
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();
    boolean mReturn = false;
    if (map != null) {
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        mapSettings = map.getUiSettings();
        mapSettings.setCompassEnabled(true);
        mapSettings.setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
        mapSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


        map.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
        map.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
        mReturn = true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    final LatLng point = position;

    Marker marker = map.addMarker(createMarkerOptions("test", "snippet", point, true));
    markers.add(marker);

    // ... 
}

    @Override
public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ImageView deleteMarker = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.deleteMarker); 
    deleteMarker.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // I want to delete that "marker" if dragged over the "deleteMarker" imageview

}

@Override
public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    findViewById(R.id.deleteMarker).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: That depends on whether you are using a mapview, mapfragment or a supportmapfragment.  Post your code so this doesn't get ingnored.

Comment: @MarkBasler i am using a mapfragment. I have posted the code !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved partially, i tried this:

```
    LatLng markerLocation = marker.getPosition();
    LatLng mapCenter = map.getCameraPosition().target;
```

Positionning the delete icon on map center, i can test latitude and longitude attributes of the two above objects.

```
    if((markerLocation.latitude > mapCenter.latitude - MINLAT  && markerLocation.longitude > mapCenter.longitude - MINLNG) 
            && (markerLocation.latitude < mapCenter.latitude + MAXLAT && markerLocation.longitude < mapCenter.longitude + MAXLNG)){
       marker.remove();
    }
```

**EDIT :**

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="sn.gotech.trafficjammeu.TransparentSupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_marker"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/deleteMarker"
    />
```

`OnMarkerDragListener` overrided methods :

```
@Override
public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    deleteMarker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    // ....
}

@Override
public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LatLng markerLocation = marker.getPosition();
    LatLng mapCenter = map.getCameraPosition().target;

    float[] results = new float[1];
    Location.distanceBetween(markerLocation.latitude,
            markerLocation.longitude, mapCenter.latitude,
            mapCenter.longitude, results);
    if (results[0] / 1000 < RADIUS) // the RADIUS depends on Camera Zoom
    {
        // ... remove marker here
    }
    deleteMarker.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: hi your code and idea is superb .i have tried it but I am not understanding how to get Radius

Answer (score 2):

I think I have a better perspective concerning the answer you posted.
I was trying to do the exact same thing, the way I did it was to place an ImageView in the activity's layout. 
When you click on a marker the phone vibrates shortly and if you drag the marker over the trashbin image the image becomes red. When you stop dragging if the marker is on top of the trashbin the marker gets removed, otherwise it goes back to its initial position. 
My code is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/customMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.myapp.CustomMapFragment" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibDeleteMarker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

(places the delete icon in the middle/right of the screen)

After that I set my marker to be `draggable` and I have overidden the corresponding methods (after setting the `GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener`). I take the markers screen coordinates (the actual x,y not the lat, lng) and I check if they overlap (The following code is in my MapFragment - in the activity that hosts the fragment I do the needed findViewById etc.):

```
//This is in the activity
   deleteMarker = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibDeleteMarker);

    //This is in the MapFragment
    vibrator = (Vibrator) activity.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE); 
//you need also the permission in AndroidManifest
    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).deleteMarker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        origMarkerPos = marker.getPosition();
        vibrator.vibrate(100);
    }

@Override
public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
    final ImageView deleteMarker = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).deleteMarker;
    Point markerScreenPosition = getMap().getProjection().toScreenLocation(marker.getPosition());
    if (overlap(markerScreenPosition, deleteMarker)) {
        deleteMarker.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_delete_red);
    } else {
        deleteMarker.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_delete);
    }
}

@Override
public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
    final ImageView deleteMarker = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).deleteMarker;
    deleteMarker.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Point markerScreenPosition = getMap().getProjection().toScreenLocation(marker.getPosition());
    if (overlap(markerScreenPosition, deleteMarker)) {
        marker.remove();
    } else
        marker.setPosition(origMarkerPos);
}

private boolean overlap(Point point, ImageView imgview) {
    int[] imgCoords = new int[2];
    imgview.getLocationOnScreen(imgCoords);
    Log.e(TAG, " ****** Img x:" + imgCoords[0] + " y:" + imgCoords[1] + "    Point x:" + point.x + "  y:" + point.y + " Width:" + imgview.getWidth() + " Height:" + imgview.getHeight());
    boolean overlapX = point.x < imgCoords[0] + imgview.getWidth() && point.x > imgCoords[0] - imgview.getWidth();
    boolean overlapY = point.y < imgCoords[1] + imgview.getHeight() && point.y > imgCoords[1] - imgview.getWidth();
    return overlapX && overlapY;
}
```

I don't know if it is the best solution, but it works.
 
 **Note:** If you have an actionbar there might be an offset between the y coordinate of the marker and the imageview that you will have to take into consideration.

Comment: i have done the same thing. But i have centered the `ImageView` in my main layout, and i used the `Camera position` to find `map center` and compare its `latitude` and `longitude` to the dragging marker's lat and long. With this i managed the marker suppressing, but the problem is that this stuff depends on `camera zoom`, that's why when you `zoom+`, the `delete area` increases, and when you `zoom-`, it reduces.